# Substitute reverse proxy HTML with dynamic content in Ngnix

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm setting up a reverse proxy for internal testing of various websites via multiple backends.

In order to be able to dynamically add backends, I'm using a wildcard subdomain and parts of the `server_name` to extract settings for my Nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name   ~^(?<domain>.+)\.internal-checks(?<bundle>[0-9])\.mycompany\.com$;

    [...]

    proxy_set_header Host $domain;
    proxy_pass http://10.0.0.$bundle:8080;
```

So far, so good. What I'm having an issue with is:

**How can I replace all the occurrences of** `http://$domain` **with** `http://$domain.internal-checks$bundle.mycompany.com` **within the content I receive from the backends?**

This needs to be done in order to adjust all the links in the content to match the reverse proxy's wildcard DNS.

My current attempt is to use `subs_filter`. If I'm using hard coded values the substitutions work:

```
subs_filter http://www.my-site.com http://www.my-site.com.internal-checks1.mycompany.com r;
```

But whatever combination I tried, subsitution with variables only ends up with the original content. This is my latest shot:

```
subs_filter http://$domain http://$domain.internal-checks$bundle.mycompany.com r;
```

How does `subs_filter` expect variables to be used?

Comment: `sub_filter` doesn't accept variables in first argument. Try to use Lua instead http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#body_filter_by_lua

Comment: or script the creation of your nginx server blocks so they don't contain variables.